# Representing any number using only 0

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics

I am afraid to even ask this question, but this is something that was asked over a breakfast table by a friend of mine.

> How do I represent a number, say 4, by using just **zeros** as a numeral in tandem with any function or mathematical operator(s)?

Now one way to do this is by using a *factorial*, since $0!=1$:
$$0! + 0! + 0! + 0!$$
Another way uses $\cos 0=1$:
$$\cos 0+\cos 0+\cos 0+\cos 0$$
Also, the topmost  $1$ on *Pascal’s Triangle* is the zero$^{th}$ row, zero$^{th}$ entry, i.e.,  $0C$$_0$ = $1$.

The *Partition function* , *P(n)* is , by convention , defined as $1$ for $n=0$, i.e. , $P(0) = 1$.

Is there any other way I could possibly achieve this?I would be more interested to know the functions which when applied on zero produce non-zero results , like the ones mentioned earlier in the question, rather than semantic manipulations or visual representations.

Comment: Why the hell would you and your friend want this?

Comment: It started off as more of a philosophical debate that zero holds up infinity and then took rather this silly turn. Besides imagine designing a scientific calculator with just a 0 digit-button.

Comment: Although not "$0$", I like $|\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(\emptyset)))|$

Comment: The problem with your question is the meaning of "just zeros". None of your examples consists of ""just zeros". So you would have to define what you mean.

Comment: @naveendankal, you can click on the "reopen" button just below your *question* in order to have it reopened.

Comment: I did already, thanks!

Answer (score 22):

Peano says: with the [successor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Successor_function).

$$4=S(S(S(S(0))))$$

Answer (score 17):

You could try using unary with $0$. So $4_{10}$ is $0000$ in unary.

---

Also, this usually works:

```
       0
     0 0
   0   0
 0     0
0000000000
       0
       0
       0
```

Comment: Your examples separate the symbol $0$ from its standard meaning: the value of zero. In a similar way we could introduce *bogo numerals* (as opposed to Arabic numerals) with the symbol $0$ meaning four, then just write $0$.

Comment: OP did ask to use only zero, so even if this $0$ isn't the same as the one with the usual arithmetic properties, it wouldn't take anyone more than  couple of guesses to tell what $0000$ means. I think. Also, I took the idea of *only* zero literally. So the first example is only zeros representing 4.

Comment: OK, your ways are imaginative and they as well may be what OP wants. I'm just pointing out they are semantic tricks more than math tricks. My feeling is it should be explicitly noted here on Mathematics Stack Exchange.

Comment: @ O. Von Seckendorff : your answer is creative but I am more interested in the Mathematical representation , maybe some function that translates 0 into 1 or something like the Cos and factorial.

Comment: If "four" is represented by 0000, then "one" is represented as '0'. Which makes it impossible to distinguish between "zero" and "one" as both are written as '0'. Unless one would like to write zero as '' (empty). However, inventing a symbol for zero usually is considered as a milestone, and this would revert it. TL;DR -> I think that 4 should be written down as '00000' (five zeros).

Comment: why five zeroes?

Comment: @naveendankal Five zeroes because Sjoerd would like the lonely symbol $0$ to still mean zero. The number one must be something else then, it may be $00$. In the answer the number one is just $0$ which leaves no useful way to represent the real zero. Keep adding $0$ symbols and you will see the number four needs five symbols in Sjoerd's notation.

Answer (score 11):

$$\Large{\vert\{}\normalsize{ 0,\{0\},\{\{0\}\},\large{\{}\normalsize{\{\{0\}\}}}\large{\}}\Large{\} \vert}$$

Comment: Is that what they call a family tree?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq I've never heard that phrase in math.

Answer (score 3):

A solution only using "$0$" once is

$$\large\sqrt{\left\lceil\exp(\exp(\exp(0)))\right\rceil}=4$$

But I admit, that it is not very aesthetic.

Comment: Use Mathjax with HUGE. It could be nice !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Decided to use `\large` instead, feeling that `\huge` is overkill.

Comment: It might be a good idea to use $\exp^n$ or $\exp \circ \dots\circ\exp$ to represent successive iterations of $\exp$, and $\lceil\cdot\rceil$ for ceiling.

Comment: @Henry W $1)$ I do not know how to produce the ceil braces. (If you know it, you can edit the answer) $2)$ "$exp^n(x)$ would contain other digits. We are only allowed to use "0" as a digit here.

Answer (score 3):

Well $ 4 = (0!+0!)^{(0!+0!)} $

And we could take this notation: $$x_n=\sum_{n=0!}^n 0!$$ as we are not explicitly using the number $n$ , but rather this is just short hand.

So now we may express $e$ in terms of $0$ as $$lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\displaystyle (0!+\frac{0!}{x_n})^{x_n} $$

or if you prefer:

$$ e = (0!+0!)+\cfrac{0!}{0!+\cfrac{0!}{(0!+0!)+\cfrac{0!}{0!+\cfrac{0!}{0!+ \cfrac{0!}{(0!+0!)^{(0!+0!)}+\cdots               }}}}   } $$

but of course this is all rather ridiculous!

Of course assigning $x_n$ in this way, is essentially the same way as assigning a number such as $4$ or $300$ -- it is arbitrary, which opens all such thought on the proper existence of numbers ... but this is starting to dig far deeper into your silly question!!!

Comment: That's exactly what has been troubling me too with regards to this question. It sounds both stupid and silly and deep and profound at the same time, maybe less mathematically but more philosophically. It leads to a the vulnerability of the existence of numbers and raises a slight doubt whether they are essential or inconsequential. I am glad that you added that last paragraph to your answer because this is exactly what my fear was when I stated this question. An extra up for that para!!

Comment: Thus the unreasonable effectiveness of mathematics follows!

Answer (score 2):

Arguably the von-Neumann construction does exactly that: It identifies each natural number with the set of natural numbers below (where $0$ is considered a natural number).

In that construction, of course $1=\{0\}$: The only natural number below $1$ is $0$. Obviously this only uses $0$ (and the set construction, but then, you were obviously willing to use extra constructions as long as they are not themselves $0$).

Furthermore, $2=\{0,1\}$. Now, this obviously uses $1$ besides of $0$. But we've just seen that $1=\{0\}$. So $2=\{0,\{0\}\}$.

Then $3=\{0,1,2\}$. Using the previous results, we get $3=\{0,\{0\},\{0,\{0\}\}\}$.

And $4=\{0,1,2,3\} = \{0,\{0\},\{0,\{0\}\},\{0,\{0\},\{0,\{0\}\}\}\}$

So clearly $4$ (and any other natural number) can be represented using only zero.

But it's even better: I omitted the question: What is $0$? Well, $0$ is the set of natural numbers less than $0$. But there *are no* natural numebrs less than $0$. Therefore $0$ is the empty set, $0=\emptyset$.

So actually the von-Neumann construction creates all natural numbers literally out of nothing. Given the number $n$, you simply get the next natural number by appending the number $n$ as new element to itself: $n+1=n\cup\{n\}$

So $0$ is the empty set. So you get the next number, $1$, by appending $0$ as element; that is, you've got $1=\{0\}$. To get from $1$ to $2$, you append the element $1$, so $2=\{0,1\}$, and so on.

Moreover, you mention that the question arose from a discussion about infinity. And it turns out that the von-Neumann construction is exactly the way to get to infinity (and beyond!). That's because you can now ask, what is the set of *all* natural numbers. Well, if we want to consider it a number, it must be a number large enough that *all* natural numbers. That is, it is infinite. This specific number is commonly called $\omega$.

So it is infinity, right? Well, wait. If it is a number in its own right, then we can make again a set of numbers containing all natural numbers *and* $\omega$. This set by construction contains all numbers $\le\omega$, so it cannot have any "holes". But then, according to the rule, it should be *another* number, that is also larger than every natural number, and furthermore larger than $\omega$! Indeed, since we've just appended the element $\omega$ to $\omega$, so what we get should be $\omega+1$. And we can repeat that construction to get $\omega+2$, $\omega+3$, … So we get actually *infinitely many* additional infinities.

The numbers whose construction I just describes (well, strictly speaking, I only described the construction of the lowest ones) is called the ordinal numbers.

Now you may ask: What does the complete set of ordinal numbers look like? Well, here comes the next surprise: *The set of ordinal numbers does not exist!* That's seen directly from the construction. Remember how we arrived at $\omega$? Well, we had the set of all natural numbers, and we decided that the very fact that we have that set makes it a new number, that's larger than any of them.

Now imagine we'd have the set of ordinal numbers. Then by the very construction, that set itself should be an ordinal number larger than any ordinal number. But then it cannot be in that set, and therefore that set cannot be the set of ordinal numbers, as we've just found an ordinal number that's not in that set, namely the very set itself!

So you see, we've started with $0$ (actually, with literally nothing), and ended up with so many numbers that they don't even fit in a set!

Answer (score 1):

My guess is $0^0 =1$ thus $0^0 + 0^0+0^0+0^0 =4$.

Comment: Why the downvote. This is a perfectly valid way.

Comment: $0^0$  is undefined

Comment: To my knowledge, $0^0$ is widely accepted to be $1$ because of the existence of the limit $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} x^x=1$$ I am not sure, whether this convention is widely accepted as the convention that the square root should be non-negative, but I often came across this definition.

Comment: I like this because it uses only the zero symbol.  While an analyst might feel $0^0$ is undefined in some contexts, a combinatorialist will likely be happy with a value of one assigned.

Comment: @Bernard Masse Undefined? Try your Windows Calculator.

Comment: Isn't $0^0 = \prod_\text{false}0 = 1$? What else would it mean?

Comment: @Peter That limit is definitely not why $0^0$ is conventionally defined to be $1$. The reason is twofold: there is precisely one function $\varnothing\to\varnothing$, and $0^0=1$ allows us to plug $x=0$ into $\sum_n a_n x^n$ reasonably.

Comment: @Anixx Windows Calculator definitely is not an authoritative source on mathematics. Try [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0%5E0).

Comment: $0^0=1$ when the exponent is the integer 0. $0^0$ is undefined when the exponent is the real 0.

Comment: @Mateen Ulhaq Do you mean to say the calculator has an error? Report a bug! And who decides who is authoritative? Do Wolfram Alpha even claim it is undefined in "Authoritative Matrhematics" or only in their program? For instance, they define Zeta function differently than the majority of authors, so should we think that "Authoritative Mathematics" uses the Wolfram Alpha's approach?

Comment: Let me back up and say there is no authoritative source. 0^0 was hardcoded in by Microsoft employees and they chose 1 (which is fine).

Comment: The reason $0^0$ is assigned to 1 is partly because of newton's Binomial expansion :
$(a+b)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n{a^k b^{n-k}}$
Replace b by 0 and n by 0 and you get $a^0 = 1$ which is what you want.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: Oh really? Are you familiar with the common constructions of the real numbers? $\mathbb{N}$ is a set of finite ordinals. $\mathbb{R}$ is a set of equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences. They have no element in common. Yes, you can redefine $\mathbb{N}$ to be a specific subset of $\mathbb{R}$, and then there are no distinct "integer 0" and "real 0". But even then there is distinction in how you use it. In a context where the exponent is taken to be an integer, it makes no sense not to define $0^0=1$. If the exponent is assumed arbitrary real, $0^0$ should be left undefined.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: I think it will be clearer if instead of "Real 0" and "Integer 0" we talked about "real exponentiation" and "integer exponentiation", two distinct operations that we happen to use the same symbol for. For $x$ in some group and $n\mathbb{Z}$, integer exponentiation $x^n$ is defined using repeated multiplication and inverses. For $x, y\in\mathbb{R}, x\ge0$ (let's leave negative bases for now), real exponentiation is defined as $x^y=\exp(y\log x)$. The two definitions mostly coincide so it's not generally important to distinguish them, but sometimes it is.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: The whole point of defining $x^y$ for real exponents is so that it will be continuous (if we didn't want it continuous, it could be anything). Since you can't define $0^0$ so that $x^y$ would be continuous at $(0,0)$, there's no sense in defining real exponentiation there at all.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: In the combinatorics applications you use integer exponentiation, not real exponentiation. How you define $0^0$ for real exponentiation is irrelevant for them. I feel the same as you - it's very strange that you don't see that "exponentiation" is being used in two distinct ways, and that the exponentiation in algebra is very different from the exponentiation in analysis. Insisting that there's "one exponentiation to rule them all" is very 18th century thinking, mathematics has evolved a lot since then. I guess we'll just have to agree to disagree.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: The same phenomenon happens frequently. e.g., in a common construction of cardinals, cardinals are a subclass of ordinals. In that construction $\omega=\aleph_0$. What is $2^{\omega}$? If we mean the ordinal $\omega$ and ordinal exponentiation, $2^{\omega}=\omega$. If we mean cardinal exponentiation and the cardinal $\omega$, aka $\aleph_0$, $2^{\aleph_0}=\beth_1\neq\aleph_0$. Two different types of exponentiations with different definitions and results, which happen to coincide on finite numbers. Of course, this happens much more generally than with just exponentiation.

Comment: Should we make this an actual question rather than battling in the comment section of another one ?

Answer (score 1):

Every *real* number admits a binary expansion. For every occurrence of $1$ in the expansion, write $1=0^0$.

Comment: 1. You've mis-spelled "write". 2. $0^0$ is undefined. Perhaps you meant $1=\lim\limits_{x\to0}x^x$.

Comment: @barakmanos Thanks for pointing out the spelling error. Your other point is wrong. $0^0$ is $1$. This is the standard convention.

Comment: I've never heard of a unified "standard convention". What I have seen is that in particular settings where such undefined expressions arise, they are defined situationally as the limit of some expression as the parameter in question approaches $0$.

Comment: @AJY No, there is a difference between viewing $0^0$ in terms of a limit and in terms of a value. There are many functions $f,g$ such that $f(x), g(x) \to 0$ and $\lim f(x)^{g(x)}$ exists; this limit may take on many different values. I tend to think of it in "discrete" terms, not in terms of limiting behaviour. $a^b$  is the number of $b$ tuples of a set with $a$ elements. If $a=b=0$, there is $1$ such tuple, namely the empty tuple.

Comment: Yes, it takes on many different values. You're absolutely correct. That's why we typically define it contextually. You are welcome to think of it in "discrete" terms, whatever that means, but it's a mistake to attribute this habit to the mathematical community at large.

Comment: @AJY I think you and I have differing conceptions of what "$0^0$ " refers to. $0^0$ refers to the number $0$ raised to the power $0$. That's it. It does not refer to the limiting behaviour of $f(x)^{g(x)}$ ($f,g \to 0$) as both functions go to $0$. Just like $0+0$ does not refer to the limiting behaviour of $f(x) + g(x)$ (again, both of which can be assumed to tend to $0$) - it's just $0 + 0$.

Comment: Yes, but that has conflicting interpretations which I am quite certain you are familiar with. And even so, you are still discussing *your own* preferences, rather than any consensus.

Comment: @AJY Do you accept the binomial theorem? Does it hold for $(x+0)^n$? This isn't really up for debate.

Comment: @AJY Or how about the power series of $\exp$, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$ at $x=0$. Is that also disputed?

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 I don't know about you, but the binomial expansion for $(1+1)^{-1}$ does not make sense.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 I won't dispute the Maclaurin series of $\exp$, but I will argue about anyone trying to do the Taylor expansion of $e^{-x^2}$ at any point should reconsider what they understand.

Comment: Independent of the interpretation of $0^0$, in the *binary expansion* we have $1 = 2^0$, a power of $0$ does not appear.

Comment: @AJY There is a lot of places where they are not defined as a limit, you are simply lying. One even does not need any limits to define 0^0=1.

Comment: @AJY if YOU define it contextually, do not speak for all!

Comment: @AJY "you are still discussing your own preferences, rather than any consensus. " - it was YOU first who claimed there is consensus to leave it undefined.

Comment: I'm not going to continue this further. I will say this: I cannot think of a single case where the expression $0^0$ arises (besides in a college algebra course as an example of an undefined expression) such that it is not assigned a value solely as a limiting case of some particular expression. I am skeptical of claims to there being a single universally recognized convention. Arguments on convention will prove rather unfruitful, as it'll consist only of personal testimonies. I have other things to do. I apologize to @MathematicsStudent1122 for initiating this.

Comment: @celtschk I don't understand your point. The number 4, for example, can be written as $100$ in binary. This is the so-called binary expansion. With only zeroes, you can write $4=0^0 00$.

Answer (score -1):

```
0 = 0
1 = 0++
2 = (0++)++
3 = ((0++)++)++
```

and so on. This uses the syntax of C-like languages.

Comment: Maybe you could explain your notation?

Answer (score -1):

Please take it lightly ,

Add zero to a number let say x so now the new number is x0 , x0-x  = yz , 
now  u= sum y+z , now sqrt u + u to the power 0 will be 4.
Explanation u will always be 9 so sqrt 9 will be 3 and power 0 will be one so 3+1=4

Answer (score -2):

Changing my answer...
Per the question, use only *zeroes* $$\frac{\color{blue}{zero} + \color{blue}{zero} + \color{blue}{zero} + \color{blue}{zero}}{\color{blue}{zero}}$$
Note: $zero\ne0$ $\color{lightgray}{:-)}$